# Execute curl using php

Tags: php, soap, curl, soapserver

I can call a soap server using java like this

```
        Call call = new Call();
        URL url = new URL("http://soap-something.dash.com/servlet/rpcrouter");
        call.setTargetObjectURI("urn:login-transport");
        call.setMethodName("confirmPassword");
        call.setParams(a vector);
        resp = call.invoke(url, "");
```

But my question is how can I call this same function using curl and php, I have already tried this, but it may be some kind of funny code

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://soap-something.dash.com/servlet/rpcrouter?urn:login-transport");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, "confirmPassword");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("username"=>"pritom", "password"=>"pritom"));
    $head = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo "<br/>HTTP CODE: " . $httpCode;
    print_r($head);
```

But it echo http code 100 and I do not found any result from soap server. But my soap server is ok, tested by java.

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is.

Comment: Hmm, you can see my problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, except CURLOPT_HEADER needs to be either true or false (include HTTP header in output or not),

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, "confirmPassword");
```

should be

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

I can only guess what confirmPassword is, if it's a callback, you should use CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION instead.

But as Ariel pointed out, you're not telling us what the problem is.

Comment: where goes `urn:login-transport` and `confirmPassword` is function that is called.

Comment: if all you want to do is SOAP, i suggest looking into the PHP SOAP functions instead, [SoapClient](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false); // remove body
```

Then post what the output is.

Comment: same result after removing that line. getting http code 100 and nothing else.

Comment: @Pritom http code 100 means that server is waiting for the body of the request. It's a pretty unusual http code, but perhaps soap uses it. Can you verify that the url form PHP is exactly the same as the one from your java code? Check the actual soap server log, not just your source code.

Comment: @Pritom Try also setting `CURLOPT_HEADER` to false and see what it does.